# Naive question about storing some entity attributes in the database

Tags: database-design

I am designing a database-centric web application. I have noticed that some entities have attributes, which are not used in selecting, sorting, and grouping. They are just plain and simple data holders, stored in the database and updated by GUI, e. g. attribute `Middle Name` in entity `User`.

So, I am planning to store ALL these attributes together in a `varchar` field as a string (in JSON format). I think it makes the data access layer simpler since I do not need all that JSON to/from SQL conversion for each entity.  Additional benefit is to add/remove these attributes w/o altering the database schema. Does it make sense ?

Comment: You mention an "additional benefit". What are the other benefits, in your opinion? Could you enumerate them as you see them, and it might give responders something more to go on. (Hint: I don't see much upside.)

Comment: while it's easy to add/remove these attributes w/o altering the schema, that really shouldn't be a problem. What you do add is extra overhead - what if you just need a guys middle name? Now you need this huge blob of a field to be pulled down from the database and parsed to just get the middle name. What if later users want to update their middle name - you have to pull the whole thing down, parse it, present it, then on upload, pull the whole thing down and replace the middle name and reupload - it creates complexity to update / change the field.

Comment: An alternative method is to create an attribute table (AttributeID, AttributeName, AttributeValue, UserID). In this way you can pull down all records associated with a UserID and then put them in a dictionary to find a particular attribute. It's infinity expandable - just add a new AttributeName for anything. And if you remove the record it's like the attribute doesn't exist (this is how ASP.NET profile providers default setup looks)

Comment: @Paul: I think storing attributes as a JSON blob makes the data access layer simpler since I do not need all that JSON to/from SQL conversion. (I have updated the question).

Comment: @Prescott. Thank you for your suggestion to use an attribute table instead. It could be a good idea since I can write the conversion JSON to/from the attribute table only once and re-use it across my application.

Comment: the JSON isn't that bad (if thats even what you're using - server side code might be a better choice).  string manipulation would be more difficult an potentially error prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the single varchar is a good idea.  I guess you plan to append new ones at the end?  It would make supdating/deleting very difficult.

**EDIT** - (thanks nox!) - Your situation is not unique, its a common strategy called EAV (entity-attribute-value) and I use it myself along with many others.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model  Implementations of it vary, and I've suggested one below that I hope can work for you.

Try the following table structure:

> entity
>   id, name, .....
>
> attribute    - example (3, 'Middle Name')
>   id, name, [content_type], [choice_type], [parent]
>
> attribute_value - example (1, 3, 'Xavier')
>   id, attribute_id, value
>
> entity_to_attribute_value
>   id, entity_id, attribute_value_id

To get X's attributes:

```
SELECT *
FROM attribute A 
   LEFT JOIN attribute_value AV on AV.attribute_id = A.id
   INNER JOIN entity_to_attribute_value ETAV on ETAV.attribute_value_id = AV.id
WHERE ETAV.entity_id = X
```

I listed a few optional fields on attribute for the following

`content_type`:
This could be done as an enum or foreign keys to another table.  Can indicate numeric, positive numeric, string, ex.  Useful for validating input since `value` is a varchar and will allowing anything

`choice_type`:
Can indicate whether user enters whatever they want (create new attribute_value), chooses only one from those you've already set up, or chooses one-or-more that you've already set up.  On a form entry page this will dictate the kind of form element (input, select, select w/ multiple)

`parent`:
Points to another attribute for hierarchical relationships between them like country and state, for example.  This will potentially affect both the display and logic on the form page.

When generating the GUI form you'll want to make elements for all attributes, and adding new ones is as simple as a row in the table.

Comment: Just to add - this technique/scheme is called "EAV" (Entity-Attribute-Value) so OP can look up more info if he wishes so

Comment: yes i should've added that.  presumed from the title he already knew and was looking for help with an implementation, but now that you mention it he didn't quite name it exactly.  Thanks Nox - I'm going to edit that in to make it more obvious.

Comment: Thanks, Nox and and Darkstar! I did not know about this EAV technique.